# how to post with retrofit to WCF service

Tags: android, api, wcf, retrofit

i researched many pages, but nothing could answer me.
Here is my code on android

**RaceAPI.java**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/Service1.svc/GetData1")
void GetData1(@Field("title") List<String> m, Callback<String> cb);
```

this is how i post data

```
  RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://10.0.1.12:54253/")
            .build();
    final RaceAPI  race= adapter.create(RaceAPI.class);
    race.PostData(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            int a;
            a=1;
        }
    });
```

this is my WCF service signature

```
            [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "/PostData")]
            String PostData(List<String> m);
```

but i am receiving this error on Android in retrofit callback failure()

> retrofit.RetrofitError: 400 Bad Request

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed i made it work with some changes in retrofit interface.

Added Headers attribute to the method declaration in interface.

```
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@POST("/Service1.svc/PostData")
void PostData(@Body SpeechModel m, Callback<SpeechModel> cb);
```

I made data to be passed bind with the body of the interface.(i removed @FormUrlEncoded)

I made custom class to send and retrieve from the server. i couldn't send as string or string array(there might be someways. couldn't find it.)

```
   SpeechModel m = new SpeechModel();
        m.setSpeechId(5);
        m.setSpeechText("something");
        race.PostData(m, new Callback<SpeechModel>() {
            @Override
            public void success(SpeechModel PostDataResult, Response response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                int a;
                a=1;
            }
        });
```

WCF service signature, changed argument type and return type.

```
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",            
  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  BodyStyle= WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
  UriTemplate = "/PostData")]
  SpeechModel PostData(SpeechModel m);
```